# Checking strings in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was wondering what I am doing wrong. I have a table loaded into a 1d array, with each element being a row, and the values are tab delimited.

For example (instead of \t, it is actually the whitespace tab):

```
array[0] = "##Misc data 1";
array[1] = "##Misc data 2";
array[3] = "#Field1\tField2\tField3";
array[4] = "LOW\tABC\tDEF"
array[5] = "HIGH\tXYZ\t123"
```

I want the array to be

```
array[0] = "";
array[1] = "";
array[3] = "#Field1\tField2\tField3";
array[4] = ""
array[5] = "HIGH\tXYZ\t123"
```

The code I currently have is

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!array[i].contains("\t") || !array[i].contains("HIGH") || !array[i].contains("#")) {
            array[i] = "";
        }
    }
```

This makes it so that all of the elements in the array are "". I want to know why that is and what I can change to make it so.

EDIT: Thank you for all your comments and suggestions, I have figured it out with your guidance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].contains("\t")) {
        if (array[i].contains("HIGH") || array[i].contains("#")) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            array[i] = "";
        }
    } else {
    array[i] = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: may be it is me but what you want is kind of unclear to me. can you clarify better plz?

Comment: Right, in your example, why does "LOW\t" get nulled out, but "HIGH\t" does not?  Is it that one term takes precedence?  You test for all of those and then always do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because for each String, you are matching at least one of the conditions in your `or` statement.

Conditions:

1. Array doesn't contain tab (`!array[i].contains("\t")`) **OR**
2. Array doesn't contain "HIGH" (`!array[i].contains("HIGH")`) **OR**
3. Array doesn't contain "#" (`!array[i].contains("#")`)

Strings, and what they match:

1. "##Misc data 1"; (Matches #1 & #2, no tab, no "HIGH")
2. "##Misc data 2"; (Matches #1 & #2, no tab, no "HIGH")
3. ???
4. "#Field1\tField2\tField3"; (Matches #2, no "HIGH")
5. "LOW\tABC\tDEF"  (Matches #2, no "HIGH")
6. "HIGH\tXYZ\t12 (Matches #3, no "#")

Without knowing more about your requirements, I suspect you don't mean to OR these together, or you are putting a not (`!`) somewhere where you want a match.

Comment: ohhh I see. How could I make it like the array I want (the second array)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all lines with a tab in it which start with # or HIGH, then

```
if (!array[i].contains("\t") ||
       (!array[i].startsWith("HIGH") && !array[i].startsWith("#")) {
  array[i] = "";
}
```